# How do I submit the iWatch app to the App Store?

Tags: app-store, submit, watchos

I want to submit iWatch app on appstore.
But I can't find the option for iwatch.
Can you please help me for this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. When you create a new Watch App project (not an iOS App with Watch App), note that it creates a Watch App target, a Watch Extension target, AND an almost empty iOS App target (no code, storyboards, xcassets, but under build phases it is dependent on the Watch App and embeds the Watch app).
> 2. On App Store Connect, you create a new iOS app project for your independent Watch app, but only fill in the data related to the Watch part of the project.
> 3. Archive and upload your project as you normally would a standard iOS project.

Voila! (And yes, that is not intuitive).
find more [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/124943) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/watchos/submit/)

Comment: Okay, I will follow the instructions.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome.. and please tell me if it did work.. good luck

Comment: @VenusDevelooer did it work with you?

Comment: Hello Jabbar
It worked!
Thanks so much.

Comment: @VenusDeveloper I am glad to hear that

Comment: I think I can submit on exist iOS app as well.

Comment: Hello @Jabbar
Can you please help me for next question as well?
"Why doesn't play radio station on real iWatch?"

Answer (score 0):

alright, it's possible to submit as a watch version on existing iOS app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to submit on the existing iOS app.
But you need to create the watch app bundle ID from iOS app ID.